# How to insert pdf in div using jsPDF in angular 4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, pdf

I am creating a small angular 4 application. I want to insert newly generated pdf into a div. I am using [jspdf](http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/) to generate pdf. I want to generate pdf on the fly an insert into div (something like this http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/). Here is my code:

```js
export class mycompo implements OnInit {
    pdfSrc: string;
    doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');

    constructor(private globals: DataService) {
        this.pdfSrc= "src/assets/pdf/pdf.pdf";
        this.doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
        this.doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world.');
        this.doc.save('src/assets/pdf/test.pdf');

    }

}
```

```html
<div>
    <label>PDF src</label> <br/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="PDF src" [(ngModel)]="pdfSrc">
</div>
<pdf-viewer [src]="pdfSrc" [render-text]="true" style="display: block;"></pdf-viewer>
```

In this code, I am trying to save and open later but it not working.
I think there are basically two possibilities:

1. Generate file, save and open when done.
2. Generate file and insert it directly into a div.

Can you please help with this.

Comment: Are you creating pdf after submitting the text value that is entered in the textbox?

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth, not really pdf is generated in the background with data download from the server and inserted into div.

Comment: when you give this `this.pdfSrc= "src/assets/pdf/pdf.pdf";` in constructor, is the pdf already generated?

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth normally not yet.

Comment: so you don't have to give the path in the constructor. once you save the file, then only assign the path URL to `pdfSrc`. this should work.

Comment: @AbhishekEkaanth thank for your comment the issue is that I cannot save the file. When you save, it downloads automatically.